# Comparing data of same column

Tags: r

I have large number of data. Following data is just the sample:

```
Day   Time(hr)   Data   
1        0:00      23.5
1        1:00      22 
1        2:00      25
1        3:00      29
2        0:00      27
2        1:00      24
```

I want the result as:

```
Day Time(hr)  Data   Corrected data
1   0:00      23.5   = 23.5
1   1:00      22     =if((23.5-23.5*10%) <= 22 <=(23.5*10%+23.5),22,interpolation)
1   2:00      25    =if((22-22*10%) <= 25 <=(22*10%+22),25, interpolation)
1   3:00      29    =if((25-25*10%)<=29<=(25*10%+25),29, interpolation)
2   0:00      27    = 27
2   1:00      24    = if((27-27*10%)<= 24 <=(27*10%+27),24, interpolation)
```

The method of interpolation will be linear. Since I am new to r programming, I could not link each column using if else statement. How can I check those data and interpolate in false condition?

Comment: So, the calculations restart on each new day? And then you want to linearly interpolate the values if they are within +/- 10% of the previous hour?

Comment: Yeah calculations restart in each day. If the value is not within +/-10% of previous value, then I want to interpolate.

Comment: Those details would be good to edit in to your question (hint hint) :-)